# Format a string that is a date to display D/M/Y

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime, formatting

Currently I have a date in my clients data table and it is stored as a varchar.
Im am using MVC3 with Razorviews.
how can I format this date when it is by default a string to render as D/M/Y?

Currently it renders the same as it's stored in the db: YY/MM/DD

Or for that matter, how can I format any string to display any way I wish.

For example, is there a way to change a string in the database that is a string: Product # 1

and in my view I can have it render as "Coffee Cup".?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string YourNewDateTimeString = 
    String.Format("{0:yy/MM/dd}", Convert.ToDateTime(YourDateTimeStringFromTheDb));

// do something with YourNewDateTimeString
```

As for rendering a string of `"Product # 1"` to `"Coffee Cup"`, you will surely have to do some form of string mapping, as there is no correlation between those two strings.

Comment: This code seems to work however the variable : YourNewDateTimeString gets a green squiggly line saying this variable is only assigned to.. and that's it. No more information that error/warning.

Comment: @EB That's because the compiler will give you a warning if you assign but never use a variable.

Comment: @EB What doesn't work?  Do you get an error?  Not the right format you're looking for?